# Dataweave 2 - Cannot coerce String to DateTime

Tags: datetime, timezone, mule, dataweave, string-to-datetime

I have a **String** as DateTime like this `2019-05-21 00:00:00.000`.

This is the code that I use in Dataweave 2 to transform String to DateTime:

```
SourceDate: payload.Source_date as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"}
```

But it returns this error:

> "Cannot coerce String (2019-05-21 00:00:00.000) to DateTime, caused
>   by: Text '2019-05-21 00:00:00.000' could not be parsed at index 10

I need to use 'T' and Z to use the TimeZone automatically.

What could be the problem?

Comment: "I need to use 'T' and Z to use the TimeZone automatically." - then you'll need those to be in the string that you're parsing. Currently your value has a space between the date and the time, and no Z at the end. Where does the value come from, and are you able to change its format?

Comment: It cames from a CSV file, Which is the format it expect?

Comment: You're specifying the format it's expecting: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`. Basically you've got to make the format you specify match the data you've got... or modify that data yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LocalDateTime which will use the current timezone:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
SourceDate: payload.Source_date as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"}
```

And you can add the timezone:

```
SourceDate: payload.Source_date as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"} >> "GMT+1"
```

Comment: The problem is that it set the same date `2019-05-21 00:00:00.000`. It doesn't adds one hore more if I am using it from GMT+1 for example.

Comment: updated answer if that helps {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"} >> "GMT+1"